# How to allow access to a 'Page' on CakePHP2

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

At controllers we can do it with:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();     
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'view', 'edit', 'index', 'verify', 'delete'); 
}
```

But how to do it on a Page whose controller is by default PageController?
I have tried the same that I use in other controllers and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the PagesController to your app folder and then you can edit it there.

So in lib/Cake/Controller copy the file PagesController.php to app/Controller.

You can than edit this file to control the static pages you have.

Comment: Are you sure? So you have your pagescontroller.php in app/Controller, and then you copied the function you have in your post?  Do you get any error? Or what happens

Comment: Yeah i am sure :), i have my PagesController in my folder app/Controller with the rest of my controllers. Then i copy and paste the beforeFilter function i use on my other controllers and i change the actions to the name of the pages. It just doesn't work. It needs to login to see those pages.